# DrawRectangle draws rectangle under graphics instead of over

Tags: java, swing, rectangles

When I try to draw rectangle over a board painted with a blue rectangle on top I see the rectangle is drawn under the blue one but the method for draw red rectangle is called after red one..

[image]

```
 @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    //this method paints the  blue board
    pintarTablero(getGraphics(), tableroMio, 100, 200);

   //red rectangle
   g.setColor(Color.red);
   g.drawRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
   g.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
}


 public void pintarTablero(Graphics g, int tab[][], int x, int y) {


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (tab[i][j] == 0) {
               // g.setColor(Color.blue);
                //g.fillRect(x + i * 30, y + j * 30, 30, 30);

               // g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(x + i * 30, y + j * 30, 30, 30);






            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You don't need to use getGraphics, you can just pass g in to your method. If you really want a copy you can use g.create() but make sure to dispose() the copy. It would help to know what your blue rectangle drawing code does.

Comment: public void pintarTablero(Graphics g, int tab[][], int x, int y) {


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if (tab[i][j] == 0) {
                   // g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    //g.fillRect(x + i * 30, y + j * 30, 30, 30);

                   // g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawRect(x + i * 30, y + j * 30, 30, 30);






                }
            }
        }


    }

Comment: Well my recommendation is just to do what I already suggested which is to use the Graphics object handed to paintComponent because it is not the same object as the one returned with the getGraphics method.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the coordinates of the red rectangle are the problem here. Try a `fillRect(0,0,200,200)`
It seems like it is getting drawn beside the blue square and getting clipped off the `JPanel` or whatever your `JComponent` is.

I emphasize, **seems**.

Answer (score 0):

Well seeing as how `pintarTablero` doesn't do anything messy like change the clip or something, my recommendation is to change this line:

```
pintarTablero(getGraphics(), tableroMio, 100, 200);
```

To this:

```
pintarTablero(g, tableroMio, 100, 200);
```

Because you will find that the Graphics object handed in to paintComponent is not the same one as the one returned with getGraphics. If you try inserting the following in to paintComponent:

```
System.out.println(g == getGraphics());
```

You will find that it prints `false` and this interaction may be the source of your problem. Either way, you shouldn't be using the getGraphics method inside paintComponent.